# How to display properties of a geoJson file in a popup on leaflet if the property names have special characters in them?

Tags: javascript, leaflet

Say an entry in my geoJSON file looks like this:

```
"properties": {
"MGT_acc":"SRR1965662_pass.fasta",
"Run_(NCBI)":"SRR1965662",
"MLST":313,
}
```

I want to display the value of "RUN_(NCBI)", i.e.  "SRR1965662." 
My javascript code for the popup looks like this right now:

```
 marker.bindPopup('MLST: ' + feature.properties.MLST+ '<br/>' +
 'Run_(NCBI)' + feature.properties."Run_(NCBI)" + '<br/>');
```

The MLST attribute shows up fine if I comment out the Run_(NCBI) line. How can I get this property to show if it contains special characters in the string?

Comment: do you need to show the value `'SRR1965662'` of `Run_(NCBI)` ?

Comment: @benjamin-c yes, that's correct

Answer (score 1):

Try referencing the property like this

`feature.properties["Run_(NCBI)"]`

Comment: that worked a charm! Thank you so much! Could you care to explain why this works?

Comment: See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Property_Accessors